# R selection equivalent to: select sum(z) from a where x in B

Tags: r, select

I've got a data frame temp and a vector descr.
A is made of two columns: "descr" and "imp" as follows:

```
 descr | imp 
 x        30
 y        29
 z        28
```

descr is vector as follows: c("x", "y")
I would like to do something like:

select sum(imp) from A join B on a.descr = b.descr

What I am doing is as follows:

```
sum(temp$imp[which(temp$descr %in% descr)])
```

that is only giving me a long series of zeros.

Comment: in `data.table`: `temp[x %in% descr, sum(imp)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "[" function with logical vector in the "i" argument and "imp" in the J-position:

```
sum( temp[ temp$descr %in% c("x","y"), "imp"] )
#[1] 59
```